# How to solve linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error in xcode 6.2 /objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, ios8.1

My app having one error "ld: file not found: /Users/Fine-Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NeonatalApp-bvbdhtlpdjrirqfkvwpjfynxzwfm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NeonatalApp.app/NeonatalApp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

In my app having following framework:
1)libsqlite3.dylib
2)libsqlite3.0.dylib
3)QuartzCore.framework
4)CoreGraphics.framework

But i don't understand which file is not found.